# Enable PipeView debug-flag for MinorCPU in gem5

Tags: gem5

everyone know what is the "O3PipeView"-like debug flag for the MinorCPU?

i try to use O3PipeView but trace.out is empty

gem5/build/ARM/gem5.opt --debug-flags=O3PipeView --debug-file=trace.out --debug-start=0 gem5/configs/example/se.py --cpu-type=MinorCPU --caches -c littletest.o

Comment: Hi Francesco. Have you grepped the code to see where that trace gets called from, and then tried to understand why that part of the code is being called? It would be good to try that out, and also share the results of your analysis. Also, what do you want to achieve, why do you want that flag?

Comment: hi Ciro, 
there is nothing to share, trace.out is an empty file;
i need for accademic use to show how the pipeline of an inorder-cpu degradetes.
The O3PipeView work for DerivO3CPU (OutOfOrder-cpu) and i reserch a similar result but for the MinorCPU (inorder-cpu)

Answer (score 0):

A little late but an answer won't hurt. O3PipeView is intended for out-of-order pipelines, MinorCPU is not an O3 pipeline so wont display visuals.

This is why it may work for DerivO3CPU not MinorCPU.

Answer (score 0):

try this
https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/44448

util/o3-pipeview.py -c 500 -o o3-pipeview.out --color m5out/trace.out

and is definitely needed in this command *(-o o3-pipeview.out)*